# Adding Kinesis Streams to a DynamoDB Global Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis

I have a DynamoDB global table with replicas in two regions, and I want to enable Kinesis Data Streaming. For any write to either table I want only one Kinesis event. What is the suggested approach to do this?

My question is:

Should I enable Kinesis Data Streams on one region's table only, or on all the regions?
If the latter, should they all point to the same Kinesis stream?

My expectation is that I don't need to enable Kinesis Data streams on multiple DynamoDB replicas, but only on one, as all records will be synchronized to that table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should only enable it for a single region, as if you configure it on multiple regions you will have N number of events, where N is the number of replicas.

Comment: That matches my expectation, though I was unable to find confirmation of it in the documentation, so thank you for your response!